# Создание адаптивной шапки сайта WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, float

1. Что лучше использовать для создания адаптивной шапки сайта WordPress - `float` или `flex` или `grid` или `bootstrap`?
2. Можно ли для создания меню, состоящего из двух частей, одна из которых прижата слева (один пункт меню), а другая - справа, (все остальные пункты меню), использовать `float: left` (для части слева) и `float: right` (для части справа)? (приведите пожалуйста html-код изначального положения: один пункт меню, промежуточная часть и остальные пункты меню - каркас меню с указанием технологии выравнивания).
3. (приведите пример кода, чтобы при уменьшении размера экрана часть меню справа переносилось на следующую строку, а также изначальное положение) .

Comment: Чисто мое мнение что лучше использовать flex. Grid пока поддержка не полная, а делать подобные задачи через float это мазахизм. Но это ИМХО

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. На этот вопрос здесь Вам отвечать не должны согласно правилам сайта, поскольку объективно лучшего варианта не может быть. Всё зависит от Ваших целей, а именно для каких версии браузеров Ваш сайт должен работать правильно. Попробуйте поэкспериментировать со всеми вариантами, потому что и `flex`, и `grid`, и `float` имеют свои особенности, дальше поймете как Вам удобно.
2. Пример меню с использованием `float`, где соблюдаются ваши условия

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 20px 15px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.right li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
     <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

3. Я приведу вам тот же самый пример на `float`, только с медиа-запросом в CSS для экранов с шириной viewport'а меньше 768px, при достижении этого breakpoint'а в 768 пикселей я перенесу правую часть меню на следующую строку, а остальные стили оставлю так.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 20px 15px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.right li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .left, .left li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .right {
    width: 210px;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
     <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: я планирую написать интернет магазин.

Comment: Вы можете попробовать использовать инструменты по типу Bootstrap Studio, если сталкиваетесь с трудностями, когда пишите сами код, а также воспользоваться готовыми шаблонами в WordPress, но от себя могу порекомендовать сверстать сайт вручную с помощью `flex` или `grid` при позиционировании элементов, imho.